# Find the critical points of the function $(x-2)^{\frac 23} (2x+1)$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

$$f’(x)= \frac 23 (x-2)^{\frac{-1}{3}} (2x+1) + 2(x-2)^{\frac 23}=0$$
$$\implies \frac{2(2x+1)}{3} + 2(x-2)=0$$
$$\implies x=1$$

From the graph, there are actually two points ie. $1,2$. At $x=2$, the function isn’t differentiable, so it can’t be found by this method. Is there any way to obtain $x=2$ algebraicaally?

Answer (score 3):

A [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) doesn't necessarily have to be when the derivative is $0$. It could also be when the function isn't differentiable.

At $x = 2$, the function isn't differentiable, so it is a critical point.